# Returns in a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, return-value, function-definition

I am trying to understand how to use recursion in C, and I can't get how `return` works in it.

Please consider the following code:

```
int     recur(int i)
{
    printf("recur: i = %d\n", i);
    if (i < 3)
    {
        recur(i + 1);
        return 10;
    }
    else if (i < 5)
        recur(i + 1);
    return i;
}

int     main(void)
{
    int     i = 0;
    i = recur(i);
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
recur: i = 0
recur: i = 1
recur: i = 2
recur: i = 3
recur: i = 4
recur: i = 5
i = 10
```

What does the last return, `return i`, do? Does this code even make sense?

Comment: In the `recur` function, what happens with the values that the recursive calls return? You simply throw them away. Also, I suggest you use a debugger to step through the code, stepping into the recursive calls, and see what happens.

Comment: sorry people i meant `return i` not `return 0`... I edited my code

Comment: Write a function that does nothing useful, and you will learn nithing useful from it.

Comment: @n.m. I don't agree with you, at all. or then please explain me your point of view.

Comment: A programming language is an utilitarian, pragmatic construction. It is hard to understand it if you use it not for its intended purpose, which is writing useful programs. You miss a lot of stuff this way. But if this is working for you, go ahead.

Comment: well, i don't know what i'm missing but i do know for sure what i'm getting: the explanation of a behaviour which I did not understand. this code was actually a simple test to see how the recursion worked, based on the input

Comment: If you tried to code up a function that returns a useful value, say factorial of the argument, you could probably learn it faster and without having to ask around. But whatever works for you.

Comment: I guess people have different affinities for learning. The easiest things for me to learn are concepts. The easiest things for you or some other people may be things to which you can relate in a concrete example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The recursive calls of the function **do not** influence on the returned value. Only the first `return` met in the first instance of your recursive function will return a value to the parent function. Any other `return` met will just stop the function's instance the program is currently in.

Thus as the function was called in main with the argument 0

```
int     i = 0;
i = recur(i);
```

The first `return` met is located inside of an `if` statement:

```
if (i < 3)
{
    recur(i + 1);
    return 10;
}
```

In this case, the `recur` function is called before returning a value to `main`. It will create another instance of `recur` which will do some stuff, but after this instance of `recur` has ended, the main instance of `recur` will continue and, in this case, will return 10 to the function `main`.

To know what your recursive function will return to the `main` function, you can simply comment all calls to a new instance of the function:

```
int     recur(int i)
{
    if (i < 3)
    {
        //recur(i + 1);
        return 10;
    }
    else if (i < 5)
    {
        //recur(i + 1);
    }
    return i;
}
```

In this case, this is what the program will read:

```
int     recur(int i)
{
    if (i < 3)
        return 10;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: you mean that only the return of the "main instance" of the recursive function matters? and the others are just a way to get out of the Nth instance of the recursive function, without actually returning anything to `main`?

Comment: @nounoursnoir You are right. I think that the function has a mistake that is it is designed incorrectly.

Comment: However, the main instance of the recursive function had 2 return statements, and it called these 2 return statements. How does the program know which one of these two return statement shall return a value to `main`? I tried it, and the output was `0`, but I am unsure what causes the program to return `0` instead of `10`

Comment: No, a function **never** executes more than 1 return statement per function call.

Comment: @nounoursnoir There is an if statement. If the value of i is less than 3 then the function returns 10. Otherwise it returns the value of I. The value of I inside the body of the function is not changed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I permitted myself to modify your answer in an attempt to make the answer to my question more understandable. Feel free to refuse it if you think it's not better

Comment: @nounoursnoir I added the statement return i; in the last function definition.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is one of the easiest recursive function to understand.

```
int pow(int n, int x)
{
    if (n != 1)
        return x * pow(n - 1, x)
    else 
        return x;
}
```

Let's study  `pow(3, 2) : 2^3 = 2 * 2 * 2 = 8`

First iteration :    `pow(3, 2) returns 2 * pow(2, 2)`
Second iteration :   `pow(2, 2) returns 2 * 2* pow(1, 2)`
Third iteration :    `n == 1`  so `pow(1, 2) returns x = 2 * 2 * 2 = 8`

A recursive function returns a call to itself at the `i + 1` step of the process. In order to avoid an infinite loop, you have to make sur you have a break condition, which leads to a return to something different from a self-call.

Comment: doesn't the second iteration should consist ```returns pow(1,16)``` ????

Comment: @PranshuTaneja You are right, and it is funny that you are the first one to notice this mistake after 5 years !! I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You got at least one answer which helpfully explains the behaviour of your code.

I want to provide help via a different, additional path here. Both together provide different view points for you.
For that purpose I provide a version of your code augmented by instrumentation, which tells you more verbosely what happens.
This allows you to play with the code and observe, that will give you the really helpful answer.

Note:

- the `for(c` lines are only for suggestive indentation;
  I chose not to use a function for this, feeling that it keeps the interesting function calls more prominent
- I added a parameter "nesting", it is for

  - making a part of the (hopefully useful) output
  - show that usually the recursive nesting has some influence
- I introduced a local variable "j",
  to show what happens with the reutrn values in most cases

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int     recur(int i, int nesting)
{   int c;
    for(c=0;c<nesting;c++) { printf(" ");}
    printf("recur[%d](%i)", nesting, i);
    if (i < 3)
    {   printf("i <3, calling recur[%d](%d)\n", nesting+1, i+1);
        recur(i + 1, nesting+1);
        for(c=0;c<nesting;c++) { printf(" ");}
        printf("returning 10 from recur[%d], with i==%d\n", nesting, i);
        return 10;
    }
    else if (i < 5)
    {
        int j=0;
        printf("i <5, calling recur[%d](%d)\n", nesting+1, i +1);
        j=recur(i + 1, nesting+1);
        for(c=0;c<nesting;c++) { printf(" ");}
        printf("ignored return value from recur[%d](%d) is %d", nesting+1, i+1, j);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(c=0;c<nesting;c++) { printf(" ");}
    printf("returning i from recur[%d], with i==%d\n", nesting, i);
    return i;
}

int     main(void)
{
    int     i = 0;
    i = recur(i, 0);
    printf("the last return value did not get ignored: i = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
recur[0](0)i <3, calling recur[1](1)
  recur[1](1)i <3, calling recur[2](2)
    recur[2](2)i <3, calling recur[3](3)
      recur[3](3)i <5, calling recur[4](4)
        recur[4](4)i <5, calling recur[5](5)
          recur[5](5)
          returning i from recur[5], with i==5
        ignored return value from recur[5](5) is 5
        returning i from recur[4], with i==4
      ignored return value from recur[4](4) is 4
      returning i from recur[3], with i==3
    returning 10 from recur[2], with i==2
  returning 10 from recur[1], with i==1
returning 10 from recur[0], with i==0
the last return value did not get ignored: i = 10
```

Note:
The `recur[n](m)` is of course no C syntax.
It just indicates a call to the function "recur" on nesting level "n" with parameter "m".
(Especially do not confuse the "[]" with arrays, they are not present.)

Answer (score -1):

return 0 is the return from the main function, not from your recursive code.

Comment: sorry people i meant `return i` not `return 0`... I edited my code