# Why is locally initialized object variable able to persist "state" in previous recursion stages

Tags: c#, recursion

Can someone please explain how a locally initialized object in this case "root, is able to have Left and Right properties assigned with Node objects in previous recursion stages, without passing root as function argument.

I suspect this effect is due to return statement returning Node object reference in previous  Recursion stages.
However, my understanding is that return statement is simply ending function call by removing function from Stack, only the "first original" function before any recursion started will return actual value.

Codes in C#

```
private Node<int> TestLocalVariableRecursion(int start)
    {
        Node<int> root = null;

        if(start < 5)
        {
            root = new Node<int>(start);

            root.Left = TestLocalVariableRecursion(start + 1);

            root.Right = TestLocalVariableRecursion(start + 2);
        }
        
        return root;
    }

public class Node<T>
{
    public Node(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Left { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Right { get; set; }
}
```

result of root: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdJqQ.png

Comment: Each recursion of the function has its own local variables. While they're on the call stack, so do those variables live.

Comment: referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241734/returns-in-a-recursive-function) which answer says: "The recursive calls of the function do not influence on the returned value. Only the first return met in the first instance of your recursive function will return a value to the parent function. Any other return met will just stop the function's instance the program is currently in"  Can I say in the case returning **objects** in recursion, the return object even though a local variable does influence previous recursion stages, where previous stage can store the return value?